# Ratio of space between grid columns in jquery-mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using a `jQuery Mobile` `grid`, which cuts the screen into 2 columns with 50% space in each.

Is it possible to make this 2 column grid have a ratio of 70/30? So the 2nd column's contents are moved to right.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/o489fzwk/

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"> 
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">this</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">is</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">a</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">test</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">js</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="float: right;"> 
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">7</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">8</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">9</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot ..

[image: current result]

Comment: `.ui-block-a { width: 70%; }` and `.ui-block-b { width: 30%; }` easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can insert span before div tag like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"> 
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">this</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">is</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">a</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">test</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">js</a>
    </div>
    <span style="float: right;">
    <div class="ui-block-b"> 
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">7</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">8</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">9</a>
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure a ratio is kept at all. If I add more links to 2nd column it stretches below 1st column: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/frgn25hf/1/

Comment: `<span style="float: right;width:30%;">` seems better for different screens. Want to add to answer and ill accept?